# Android: bindService() prevents me from accessing EditTexts?

Tags: java, android, service, android-edittext

I have this weird problem with Android (4.4), where I cannot access an EditText field's content via `getText().toString()` if (and only if) i started a boundService before.

I narrowed it down to the following code:

Layout (stripped to the essential parts):

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_username" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:text="@string/do sth"
    android:onClick="myFunction" />
```

Activity code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
private EditText editUsername;

private MyService myService;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act_login);
    this.editUsername = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.edit_username);

    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    bindService(serviceIntent, myServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE); // 1
}

public void myFunction(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(this, editUsername.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // 2
    Log.d(Config.LOGTAG, "user: " + editUsername.getText().toString());
}

private ServiceConnection myServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        ServiceBinder binder = (ServiceBinder) service;
        myService = binder.getService();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
        networkServiceIsBound = false;
    }
};
```

The MyService class does nothing atm and just implements the required stub methods as shown in the tutorial from android developers.

So my problem is: At marker "2" in the code, the content retrieved from the EditText is empty, no matter what I enter in the text field. Fun info: if I "hardcode" a String into the EditText in the layout (e.g. `android:text="blabla"`), this is shown.
Anyhow - the whole setup works perfectly, if I do not bind the service (i.e. delete the row marked with "1"): Then, everything I type in the text field is shown in both Toast and Log...

I guess that binding my Service like this somehow interferes with accessing the EditText's content. Honestly, I'm out of ideas... Anyone knows how to deal with this properly?